# regular expression taking out space and add comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

Working in Notepad++ I have a sets of data that look like this:

```
Fan 1, 5248  
Fan 2, 5248  
Fan 3, 5200  
Fan 4, 5296
```

I need them to look like this

```
Fan 1,5248,  
Fan 2,5248,  
Fan 3,5200,  
Fan 4,5296,
```

I need to remove the space after the comma following the Fan# and put a comma at the end of every line.

The fan numbers will always remain the same but the 4 digit number will always be different.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
([0-9]+,) ([0-9]+)
```

with

```
\1\2,
```

Answer (score 1):

Find `^Fan (\d), (\d+?)$`

Replace `Fan \1,\2,`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   ,\K ([0-9]+) $
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1,
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

You can test it with your example at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vT0xO5).

Please note that both previous answers are good ones! This is just another way of doing it, using 1 instead of 2 capture groups.